# Add to array if not empty returned

Tags: php

I use a function to check if multiple inputs are empty or not.

Here is the function in `functions.php`:

```
function isEmpty($input){
    if(empty($input)){
        return "Input required";
    }
}

function checkLenth($input){
    if(strlen($input) < 3){
        return "Input length must be more than 3";
    }
}
```

Then I call the function in a differnet file for all inputs:

```
isEmpty($_POST['name']);
isEmpty($_POST['email']);

checkLength($_POST['name']);
```

I want to add the messages to an array, So I do the following:

```
$errors = array();

$errors[] = isEmpty($_POST['name']);
$errors[] = isEmpty($_POST['email']);

$errors[] = checkLength($_POST['email']);
```

This works fine if these fields are empty. But if not the array contains empty strings.

How to avoid this so that the array only contains the messages and if no errors don't add to the array?

Comment: You will need to check what the function returns to decide if it should go into the array anyway, so you might as well skip your function and just do: `if (empty($_POST['name'])) { $errors[] = 'Name is required'; }`.

Comment: you could try with an `if(...)` condition?

Comment: Not sure how a list of `"Input required"` messages is really that helpful, @MagnusEriksson idea is much more useful.

Comment: @NigelRen I didn't add the whole function with the whole message. I just wanted to explain it

Comment: There is another downside to your function. It's that you still need to check if `$_POST['name']` etc are set before trying to pass them into your function, or you'll get "undefined array key/index" warnings if they don't exist. By using the function, you first need to check if they exist, then pass them to the function, and then check the response. That's three checks per value instead of just having one `if` per value and much added code and complexity for no gain what so ever.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The function and where I call it are 2 different files + there are more validation rules like length

Comment: We can only comment/answer about the code we see.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope that helps. There are 2 files:
1- for functions
2- file where I call the function

There are multiple validation functions

Answer (score 1):

**try this solution**

```
// $errors is global 
$errors = array();

isEmpty($_POST['name']);
isEmpty($_POST['email']);

function isEmpty($input){
    if(empty($input)){
        global $errors;
        $errors[] = "Input required";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first check if the result is empty.
$errors = array();

```
if ($info = isEmpty($_POST['name'])) {
     $errors[] = $info;
}

if ($info = isEmpty($_POST['email'])) {
     $errors[] = $info;
}
```